# How to pandas.DataFrame insert redis and data append it?

Tags: python, dataframe, redis, insert, append

I want to add data to redis now.

**My purpose is to split the data and insert it into redis little by little.**

After inserting pandas.DataFrame into redis, I want to add data

We've inserted the Dataframe to redis now, but we don't know how to keep and add existing data.

for example:

```
log_df_v1 ## DataFrame_v1
```

> ```
>     session_id                               connect_date     location categories join    page_out
> 0 5fd1e923-d145-40cc-bf38-3b1156af5eb6    2020-01-01 00:14:24 경기도        4    0   1
> 1 5fd1e923-d145-40cc-bf38-3b1156af5eb6    2020-01-01 00:13:13 경기도        4    0   0
> 2 5fd1e923-d145-40cc-bf38-3b1156af5eb6    2020-01-01 00:13:10 경기도        4    0   0
> 3 5fd1e923-d145-40cc-bf38-3b1156af5eb6    2020-01-01 00:13:10 경기도        4    0   0
> 4 62de8537-e79f-4d67-8db5-57a26b89a42d    2020-01-01 00:10:52 경기도        3    0   1
> ```

step 1. dataframe to redis set

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host="localhost", port=6379, db=0)
log_dic = log_df_v1.to_dict()

log_set = json.dumps(log_dic,ensure_ascii = False).encode('utf-8')
r.set('log_t1',log_set)
```

> True

step 2. Get data from redis, Make it DataFrame

```
log_get = r.get('log_t1').decode('utf-8')
log_dic = dict(json.loads(log_get))
data_log = pd.DataFrame(log_dic)
data_log
```

> ```
>     session_id                               connect_date     location categories join    page_out
> 0 5fd1e923-d145-40cc-bf38-3b1156af5eb6    2020-01-01 00:14:24 경기도        4    0   1
> 1 5fd1e923-d145-40cc-bf38-3b1156af5eb6    2020-01-01 00:13:13 경기도        4    0   0
> 2 5fd1e923-d145-40cc-bf38-3b1156af5eb6    2020-01-01 00:13:10 경기도        4    0   0
> 3 5fd1e923-d145-40cc-bf38-3b1156af5eb6    2020-01-01 00:13:10 경기도        4    0   0
> 4 62de8537-e79f-4d67-8db5-57a26b89a42d    2020-01-01 00:10:52 경기도        3    0   1
> ```

step 3(**Question**). I want to add Dataframe(log_df_v2) to redis.
However, I need to keep existing DataFrame(log_df_v1)

```
log_df_v2 ## DataFrame_v2
```

> ```
>           session_id                              connect_date        location    categories  join    page_out
>  20000    f28e7b23-5ad0-460f-b50e-e6fe0b5edff6    2019-12-29 16:03:39 서울특별시   12  0   0
>  20001    e284ca69-333f-4cb8-84c9-485353a4ed74    2019-12-29 16:03:38 경기도 4   0   1
>  20002    ea348aa8-aa52-4ee2-84da-f000020c1ecf    2019-12-29 16:03:15 경상북도    1   0   0
>  20003    36b9795c-d38f-4ec1-8f49-0eae9cecd0b6    2019-12-29 16:03:12 경상북도    1   0   0
>  20004    f83e403e-16f5-4e31-8265-3ad40d9be969    2019-12-29 16:03:12 경상북도    1   0   0
> ```

**I want to Result:**

```
log_get = r.get('log_t1').decode('utf-8')
log_dic = dict(json.loads(log_get))
data_log = pd.DataFrame(log_dic)
data_log
```

> ```
>     session_id                               connect_date     location categories join    page_out
> 0 5fd1e923-d145-40cc-bf38-3b1156af5eb6    2020-01-01 00:14:24 경기도        4    0   1
> 1 5fd1e923-d145-40cc-bf38-3b1156af5eb6    2020-01-01 00:13:13 경기도        4    0   0
> 2 5fd1e923-d145-40cc-bf38-3b1156af5eb6    2020-01-01 00:13:10 경기도        4    0   0
> 3 5fd1e923-d145-40cc-bf38-3b1156af5eb6    2020-01-01 00:13:10 경기도        4    0   0
> 4 62de8537-e79f-4d67-8db5-57a26b89a42d    2020-01-01 00:10:52 경기도        3    0   1
>  20000    f28e7b23-5ad0-460f-b50e-e6fe0b5edff6    2019-12-29 16:03:39 서울특별시   12  0   0
>  20001    e284ca69-333f-4cb8-84c9-485353a4ed74    2019-12-29 16:03:38 경기도 4   0   1
>  20002    ea348aa8-aa52-4ee2-84da-f000020c1ecf    2019-12-29 16:03:15 경상북도    1   0   0
>  20003    36b9795c-d38f-4ec1-8f49-0eae9cecd0b6    2019-12-29 16:03:12 경상북도    1   0   0
>  20004    f83e403e-16f5-4e31-8265-3ad40d9be969    2019-12-29 16:03:12 경상북도    1   0   0
> ```

How to insert log_df_v1 and then log_df_v2 into redis?

**All I want is to save data on Redis.**

Please help me...